# Approximating powers of integers with each other

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to understand the essence of the $abc$ and couple connected conjectures (Tijdeman's and Pillai’s).
One obvious step is to try to approximate powers of integers with powers of other integers: $x^m \approx y^n$.
I found it fascinating how fast powers of integers move away from each other.
Is there a simple explanation why this is happening?

Here is my attempt.
Let us define the distance between two positive integers $x$ > $y$ as $d_m(x,y) = \min |x^m - y^n|$ for a fixed $m$.

Since $x^m - y^n = x^m - x^{n \cdot \log_xy}$, the minimum is achieved when $n \cdot \log_xy \approx m$, or $n \approx m \cdot \log_yx$.

Denoting $[a]$ as either *floor* or *ceiling* of $a$, and $\{a\}$ as the fractional part of $a$:
$n = [m \cdot \log_yx] = m \cdot \log_yx + \varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon = - \{m \cdot \log_yx\}$ or $\varepsilon = 1 - \{m \cdot \log_yx\}$, $|\varepsilon| < 1$.

Substituting $n$:
$x^m - y^n = x^m - y^{m \cdot \log_yx + \varepsilon} = x^m - y^{m \cdot \log_yx}y^{\varepsilon} = x^m - x^my^{\varepsilon} = x^m(1 - y^{\varepsilon}) \approx x^m \log y \cdot \varepsilon $.

Thus, $d_m(x,y) \sim x^m$, unless $|\varepsilon|$ decreases faster than $x^{-m}$.

Can $|\varepsilon|$ converge to $0$ fast enough?

The case when $\log_yx$ is rational is simple.
Then $|\varepsilon| = 0$ for $m = kq$, where $\log_yx = p/q$, $k = 1, 2, 3, ...$

Let us take $\log_yx$ that is not rational.
We can expect the digits in the decimal representation of $\log_yx$ appear more or less randomly.
This makes the probability of getting $|\varepsilon| < 10^{-k}$ proportional to $10^{-k}$.
But then $m$ must be proportional to $10^{k}$, and $d_m \sim x^{10^k} \cdot 10^{-k}$ is a fast increasing function.

For example, for $x = 3$ and $y = 2$ $\varepsilon$ reaches $10^{-3}$ (and $10^{-5}$) on $m = 665$: $ 665 \cdot \log_{2}3 \approx 1054.000063$
But for $m = 665$ $\varepsilon$ must be about $3^{-665}$ in order to "beat" the $x^m$ component.

Other extreme examples:
$\log_{2}268435455\approx 27.9999999946$
$592 \cdot \log_{2}37667 \approx 8998.99999999933$
$2101 \cdot \log_{3}483197 \approx 25030.0000000000024$

Clearly, it is highly unlikely to find such a pair of $x$, $y$ that $\{ m \cdot \log_yx \} \approx x^{-m}$.

Does it make sense?
Are there better explanations why $x^m$ cannot be accurately approximated with $y^n$ (unless $x$ and $y$ have a common root)?
Are there instruments to investigate the behavior of the fractional parts $\{ m \cdot \log_yx \}$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture#Pillai's_conjecture

Comment: @lhf This is confusing. The stories and the definitions of Tijdeman's and Pillai's conjectures look different in Wikipedia and in the referenced Narkiewicz's book.